# How much memory does a bitmap cost when in different drawable folder

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have been bothered by this question for a while now.
After googling it without finding too much useful information, I came here for help.
Suppose I have an image(resolution 100px*100px), and then set it to an ImageView(w*h 100dp*100dp).
If the device type is hdpi, how much memory will it cost when I put the image in drawable,drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-nohpi folder?
Is there a rule  which we can rely  to get the result?
Thanks guys.

Comment: it depends on the size of the image, obviously you want a bigger image in an xhdpi folder than you would in hdpi folder so that it looks better on a higher screen resolution. otherwise you will just get a blown up blurry image

Answer (score 2):

Drawable class is the base class for all classes of graphics. This is a general abstraction for your subject on canvas Canvas. So you can create Bitmap from it.

First of all it depends of config which set to bitmap. You can calculate it :

```
/**
 * A helper function to return the byte usage per pixel of a bitmap based on its configuration.
 */
static int getBytesPerPixel(Config config) {
    if (config == Config.ARGB_8888) {
        return 4;
    } else if (config == Config.RGB_565) {
        return 2;
    } else if (config == Config.ARGB_4444) {
        return 2;
    } else if (config == Config.ALPHA_8) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

So you can calculate how many bytes will be allocated to this object :

[getPixels (int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
int count = pixels.length;
long allBytes = getBytesPerPixel(config)*count; // your memory allocation
```

Secondary. You need understand a hdpi,xhdpi,mdpi,etc. concept.

Suppose you have a small screen. 320x240px
Usually, devices which have this screen resolution have also low memory. So you need understand - Big picture on small screen is right way to OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of resources consumed would depend on two things:

1. What screen the device has (*ldpi*, *mdpi*, *xxxhdpi*, etc)
2. What resolutions you have provided (same sizes as above)

If you have an *ldpi* device, and you only provide an *xxxhdpi* resource, android will only keep a downscaled (**subsampled**) bitmap in memory.

**What does this mean**? It means, android loads the closest higher density resource (if available) in memory and uses it. So if you don't provide a density close to the devices, you're **wasting CPU** (down-scaling the bitmap, a very costly operation). **Android is good enough that it will only retain the required size in memory**.

However, if you load the drawable as a bitmap (rather than native methods like `setBackground()`), it will **load the full image, in memory, not a downscaled version**. That will blow up your memory.

Also, down-scaling and up-scaling can bot potentially cause artifacts, so that's another reason to go for multiple drawables.

**Rule**? If you're targeting low end devices, make sure that you always provide target density drawables.

Read this [excellent article](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) on memory management for Bitmaps in Android.